# No such table: table_image (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT image_data FROM table_image WHERE image_name= ' a '

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a bit new to SQLite so please bear with me. I am creating a table and trying to access data from it but somehow I am getting this error.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_image (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT image_data FROM table_image WHERE image_name= ' a '
```

Things that I did after the error came:

1.) Uninstalled the app and installed it again.
2.) Checked for spaces in the table creation code. It looks right to me.

I am not sure why this error is appearing then. Can someone please help me.
Thanks !!

My DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";

    // Table Names
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "table_image";

    // column names
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "image_name";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image_data";

    // Table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " ("+
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB"+")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating table
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE);

        // create new table
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Adding stuff to db in another class

```
// Calling addEntry

addEntry(name, img);

// Function to add entry

public void addEntry( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME,    name);
        cv.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE,   image);
        database.insert(DatabaseHelper.DB_TABLE, null, cv);
    }
```

Then I am tying to get data from it.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DB_TABLE, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
String selectQuery = "SELECT image_data FROM "+DatabaseHelper.DB_TABLE+" WHERE image_name= ' "+"a"+" ' ";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openOrCreateDatabase()` is not using `SQLiteOpenHelper` where you have the table creation code.

To get a `SQLiteDatabase` managed by `SQLiteOpenHelper`, call e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` on your helper object.

After fixing that, uninstall the app once more to get rid of the empty database created by `openOrCreateDatabase()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling your app and running it again?

error says "no such table: table_image", this situation can occur if you test your app with a DB with lesser number of tables and introduce a table later on.

once you relaunch your app with an additional table an older version of DB is already present and onCreate of your DBHelper will not be called and the new table will not be added in your db.

uninstalling the app will clear any previous instance of DB and onCreate will be called again and you will start with a fresh tables.